# Pyautogui - which approach is faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I'm having 3 days education seminar which isn't of much use for me, so I'm writing my program on a paper and I'm wondering something since I can't test it at-the-moment.

I'm basically scanning my screen for image, and screen is divided into 8 segments. I don't need to scan all 8 segments, but for instance now, let's say I only need to scan 5 out of those 8 where image can pop out.

Is it faster to just make `pyautogui` to scan whole screen and write down coordinates where image was seen, and I'll then know by coordinated on which screen it popped, or is it faster to make multiple `pyautogui` searches with defined regions? So is it faster if `pyautogui` searches whole screen once or if `pyautogui` makes multiple searches with defined regions, searching only 20-70% of screen?

If it depends on how much screen in the end I search, what would be aproximate percentage where one becomes faster than other? For instance: searching 4 times 50% of screen is faster than searching once 100% screen, but searching 6 times 75% of screen is slower than searching once 100%.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use the built-in `timeit` module to determine what you want to know yourself?

Comment: @martineau as mentioned, im writing big chunk of program on paper for these 3 days, Im not on my pc so I cannot test, nor will I be able to get on PC these days. The approach I take is crucial on how I'll write the rest of program(which ill probably do on paper aswell). Thats why i asked here =/

Comment: If how the *way* you search is crucial to how the rest of the program will be written, then it sounds like a poor design, so I suggest you rethink the approach you're taking. It's also possible you're doing [premature optimization](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization)—also a bad idea…

Comment: @martineau well it differs in this: searching whole screen will return coordinates which then determine on which screen it has been seen(ie coordinate 0-500, 0-500 are screen one, 500-1000,500-1000 is screen 2), while second method will have mutiple pyautogui searches with define regions. Then simply i know immediately if certain pyautogui finds it, then its the specified screen that it was searching(since that search is only in region of that screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the faster and more efficient/accurate process here would be searching the whole screen through `pyautogui` and write down the coordinates where the image was seen, and you then knowing by the coordinated on which screen it popped...
So I would reccomend using this method as the second methos would be more slower and not as efficient as this

Comment: Pure speculation…